# RocksDBStateBackend supports incremental checkpoint while FsStateBackend doesn't

Tags: apache-flink

For FsStateBackend, local checkpoint data are saved in memory, and remote persistent checkpoint data are saved in distributed file system,such as HDFS

For RocksDBStateBackend,local checkpoint data are saved in local RocksDB, and remote persistent checkpoint data is `also` saved in distributed  file system,such as HDFS.

So, I wonder why FsStateBackend doesn't provide the incremental checkpoint capabilities, since it is the same as RocksDBStateBackend,both of them store remote persistent checkpoint data on the distributed file system like HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

`FsStateBackend` is a legacy class, equivalent to using `HashMapStateBackend` and `FileSystemCheckpointStorage` (see [this documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/state_backends/#fsstatebackend)). The issue with incremental checkpoints is that it's not (yet) supported by the `HashMapStateBackend`, though [work is underway](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-151%3A+Incremental+snapshots+for+heap-based+state+backend) to add that.